# Greek letters in Windows Concole

Tags: c, windows, unicode, utf-8, console-application

I'm writting a program in C and I want to have Greek characters in the menu when I run it in cmd.exe . Someone said that in order to include Greek characters you have to use a `printf` that goes something like this:

```
 printf(charset:IS0-1089:uffe);
```

but they weren't sure.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Wait, who in this world is still using MS-DOS?

Comment: Recalling old memoirs, I remember we had to do a setting in DOS itself to change the "code page". Don't remember - it's been a long time since I coded in DOS.

Comment: @Radek me for example, developing on an embedded device for car diagnosis (legacy stuff anyway, but still in heavy use by our customers).

Comment: @Radek it's homework actually..

Comment: I suspect the question is not about MS-DOS but running in a console on Windows.

Comment: @Michael you're right. Now that I think of it I don't know why my book says MS-DOS in the first place.

Comment: Please edit the question to correctly specify if you mean legacy MS-DOS or a recent windows dos box/console.

Comment: To reinforce what Chris says, it's important to know which because the answer is *different* in the two cases; there have been profound changes in this area over the years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Output Unicode Strings on the Windows Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130979/how-to-output-unicode-strings-on-the-windows-console)

Comment: [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714), [Output Unicode to console Using C++, in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2849010/995714)...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Windows, you can:

- [set your console font](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_1252) to a Unicode TrueType font:
- emit the data using an "ANSI" mechanism

This code prints `γειά σου`:

```
#include "windows.h"

int main() {
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1253); //"ANSI" Greek
  printf("\xE3\xE5\xE9\xDC \xF3\xEF\xF5");
  return 0;
}
```

The hex codes represent `γειά σου` when encoded as [windows-1253](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253). If you use an editor that saves data as windows-1253, you can use literals instead. An alternative would be to use either [OEM 737](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_737) (that really is a DOS encoding) or use Unicode.

I used `SetConsoleOutputCP` to set the console code page, but you could type the command `chcp 1253` prior to running the program instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might only work if your console supports Greek.  Probably what you want to do is to map characters to the Greek, but using ASCII.  For C# but same idea in C.

> 913 to 936 = upper case Greek letters
>
> 945 to 968 = lower case Greek letters

Read more at Suite101: Working with the Greek Alphabet and C#: How to Display ASCII Codes Correctly when Creating a C# Application | Suite101.com at this [link](http://www.suite101.com/content/working-with-the-greek-alphabet-and-c-a128299#ixzz1NkrBamLI).

Comment: Big difference between DOS and an app that runs in the Console.

Comment: Right - but the point is to use the mapping - shift the abc's to the Greek ASCII numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can print a unicode char characters by using `printf` like this :

`printf("\u0220\n");`

this will print Ƞ

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to print a wide string.  Unfortunately, Windows needs a bit of non-standard setup to make this work.  This code does that setup inside `#if` blocks.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

/* This has been reported not to autodetect correctly on tdm-gcc. */
#ifndef MS_STDLIB_BUGS // Allow overriding the autodetection.
#  if ( _WIN32 || _WIN64 )
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 1
#  else
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 0
#  endif
#endif

#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
#  include <io.h>
#  include <fcntl.h>
#endif

void init_locale(void)
// Does magic so that wprintf() can work.
{
  // Constant for fwide().
  static const int wide_oriented = 1;

#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
  // Windows needs a little non-standard magic.
  static const char locale_name[] = ".1200";
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT );
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  static const char locale_name[] = "";
#endif

  setlocale( LC_ALL, locale_name );
  fwide( stdout, wide_oriented );
}

int main(void)
{
  init_locale();
  wprintf(L"μουσάων Ἑλικωνιάδων ἀρχώμεθ᾽\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This has to be saved as UTF-8 with a BOM in order for older versions of Visual Studio to read it properly.  Your console also has to be set to a monospaced Unicode font, such as Lucida Console, to display it properly.  To mix wide strings in with ASCII strings, the standard defines the `%ls` and `%lc` format specifiers to `printf()`, although I’ve found these don’t work everywhere.

An alternative is to set the console to UTF-8 mode (On Windows, do this with `chcp 65001`.) and then print the UTF-8 string with `printf(u8"μουσάων Ἑλικωνιάδων ἀρχώμεθ᾽\n");`.  UTF-8 is a second-class citizen on Windows, but that usually works.  Try to run that without setting the code page first, though, and you will get garbage.