# Encoding of console output stream in windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Output Unicode Strings on the Windows Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130979/how-to-output-unicode-strings-on-the-windows-console)

I try to output UTF-16 charachters to console in win32console application, but i cannot change the encoding of output stream, I try to use SetConsoleOutputCP() function but when i use next code for testing

```
    std::wcout << GetConsoleOutputCP() << std::endl;//output 866
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_WINUNICODE);              //if i set CP_UTF8 it works
    std::wcout << GetConsoleOutputCP() << std::endl;//output 866
```

I get the same result (866) for two cases. When I'm try to set `CP_UTF8` it works correct but I need UTF-16, why my attempt is failed and how can I set output stream's encoding to UTF-16?

Comment: You already asked five (!) questions all about problems related to using `wchar_t`, and you keep repeating that you "must use UTF-16". So, *why* do you have to use UTF-16 when you admit that UTF-8 just works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the encoding to UTF-16 because both, `cout` and `wcout`, write to the same *byte-oriented* stream (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) and only byte-oriented encodings are supported. UTF-16 is word oriented. This implies that the only Unicode encoding that can be written to the standard output is UTF-8.