# Issues when writing UTF-8 characters to stdout using WriteFile

Tags: c, visual-c++, file-io, utf-8, stdout

My intend is to write strings such as `ñaäïüwiç` (utf-8 encoded) using WriteFile method.
So I have the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    WCHAR str[] = L"ñaäïüwiç \n";
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    dwRead = (wcslen(str) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    BOOL bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, str, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

What this small program does is to print the following instead:

```
± a õ ´ ³ w i þ
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your use of `WCHAR` and `L"ñaäïüwiç \n"`seem to indicate you are using UTF-16, so you are probably writing UTF-16 to an UTF-8 (or ASCII) output stream. I guess that would explain the funny characters and the gaps inbetween. I also don't know if your editor can handle the characters given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your bytes are being interpreted as ASCII instead.  The character ñ in UTF-16 has a hex encoding of 0x00F1.  0xF1 corresponds to ± in ASCII codepage 437.  Same is true of the other characters that *are* printed.  It looks like the bytes, as defined by your use of UTF-16 literal, are not lost, but are rather interpreted as single ASCII bytes 0xF1 0x00 etc. by the stream.

See related post here: [How to Output Unicode Strings on the Windows Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130979/how-to-output-unicode-strings-on-the-windows-console)

That post says that you should use `WriteConsoleW` instead. The arguments for that function are the same as for `WriteFile`, except that `str` is expected to be UTF-16:

```
    DWORD dwToWrite, dwWritten;
    dwToWrite = wcslen(str);
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    BOOL bSuccess = WriteConsoleW(hParentStdOut, str, dwToWrite, &dwWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: FWIW, `ñ` is U+00F1 in Unicode (and thus in UTF-16), and 0xF1 is `±` in code page 437. So it could just as well be that 0x00F1 is interpreted as bytes 0xF1 0x00 in codepage 437 ASCII, hence the "gap".

Comment: You are likely correct; I missed the gaps in his output.