# C++ Visual Studio Unicode confusion

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, character

I've been looking at the Unicode chart, and know that the first 127 code points are equivalent for almost all encoding schemes, ASCII (probably the original), UCS-2, ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and anything else.

I wrote a loop to go through the characters starting from decimal 122, which is lowercase "z".  After that there are a couple more characters such as {, |, and }.  After that it gets into no-man's land which is basically around 20 "control characters", and then the characters begin again at 161 with an inverted exclamation mark, 162 which is the cent sign with a stroke through it, and so on.

The problem is, my results don't correspond the Unicode chart, UTF-8, or UCS-2 chart, the symbols seem random.  By the way, the reason I made the "character variable a four-byte int was that when I was using "char" (which is essentially a one byte signed data type, after 127 it cycled back to -128, and I thought this might be messing it up.

I know I'm doing something wrong, can anyone figure out what's happening?  This happens whether I set the character set to Unicode or Multibyte characters in the project settings.  Here is the code you can run.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int character = 122; // Starting at "z"
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << (char)character << endl;
        cout << "decimal code point = " << (int)character << endl;
        cout << "size of character =  " <<  sizeof(character) << endl;
        character++;
        system("pause");
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, here is the Unicode chart

http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character

Comment: What, precisely, do you consider to be wrong?

Comment: The font used by `cout` might depend on the locale. Where I live we used to have åäö right after z in 7-bit "ASCII".

Comment: @AndyG Well for example if you assign a value 163, or U+00A3 to a data type, (let's forget 'char' data type because char is signed and cycles around to -128 after 127, but like an int or a short int, or an unsigned 8 bit data type (if they exist), and print it as a char, you should get the pound sign.  No?  But none of my numbers correspond to the Unicode chart, it's all just random after 127.

Comment: The bytes you are printing do not get interpreted as Unicode. If I recall correctly, they get interpreted as Windows-1252.

Comment: @immibis No, sorry, I just looked up the 1252 code page and it's nothing like what I'm getting from that program I wrote up there.  Following the tilde(~) (decimal code point 126) 0x007E, I get a question mark in a box, then a 'c' with a cedilla (tail), then a 'u' with an umlaut/diaresis (two dots above it), then an e with an acute accent above it, then an 'a' with a circumflex accent above it, then an 'a' with with umlaut, then an 'e' with grave accent, then an i with umlaut, etc.

This is so confusing.  It's supposed to be Unicode!!!,  I don't get it.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice It is ***not*** supposed to be Unicode. You're not using any API functions that support Unicode ("wide characters"), you're not using wide streams, and you're printing `char`s which can't hold values higher than 255 anyway.

Comment: @immibis Sorry, I know signed one-byte chars can only store from -128 to 127, which is why I made it an int (4 bytes), it follows the Unicode code page up to 127 and then goes haywire.  If I wanted to print the British pound sign for example, U+00A3 (Dec 163), how would I do it?

Comment: 1) Project settings affect which Win32 API functions get called: …A or …W. A is for ANSI, W is for UTF-16.

Comment: 2) ANSI is not one character set. It is the one (of many) that the thread is is using for the Win32 …A functions.

Comment: 3) Unicode is a character set with many encodings. One, UTF-16, is often miscalled Unicode.

Comment: What you see in your `cout` statements all depends on the font used by the console (or other output) window you're using and not the settings in your program.

Comment: @Tom Blodget Yeah I'm aware that Microsoft has created a misnomer in their use of Unicode, which is actually UTF-16 encoding.  It you just run the program you'll see that the characters I get match no known character encoding scheme I can find, None of the UTFs, ANSI, or the Windows-1252.  Also, as this is a console program I didn't thnk calling A or W functions mattered, I'm just calling cout, or I even tried printf(), are there A and W versions for these?  Again, how do I print the British pound sign for example?  (U+00A3 (decimal 163)?  I'm starting to think this is an endianness problem?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for your help, I tried to change the fonts in the command prompt but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely the *bytes* you're printing are displayed using the console code page (sometimes referred to as OEM), which may be different than the local single- or double-byte character set used by Windows applications (called ANSI).

For instance, on my English language Windows install ANSI means [windows-1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145), while a console by default uses [code page 850](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195064.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

There are a few ways to write arbitrary Unicode characters to the console, see [How to Output Unicode Strings on the Windows Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130979/how-to-output-unicode-strings-on-the-windows-console)

Comment: You hit it on the head, thanks, bro.  That's exactly the code page I get, finally found it thanks to you.  Now just to go about fixing this.  Thanks.

Comment: @ roeland from Wikipedia: Systems largely replaced code page 850 with, firstly, Windows-1252 (often mislabeled as ISO-8859-1), and later with UCS-2, and finally with UTF-16.  So why is it I'm not getting proper UTF-16?  Is Microsoft or C++ to blame, I'm so frustrated.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice The C++ standard doesn't specify how bytes you write to the output stream are interpreted. And Windows has supported UTF-16 for a long time (the reason UCS-2 is mentioned is because they already supported Unicode when it was still a 16-bit character set)